# How to add a second item to a JSON array, only if there is one?

Tags: json, pug

I've got some Linked Data JSON, and I'm wondering how to add a second item to an array if and only if there is a second item.

In my case adding a coauthor or two coauthors to an article.

```
  script(type="application/ld+json").
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "Article",
      "headline": "#{article.title}",
      "description": "#{article.description}",
      "author": [{
        "@type": "Person",
        "name": "#{article.author && article.author.name}",
        "givenName": "#{article.author && article.author.givenName}",
        "additionalName": "#{article.author && article.author.additionalName}",
        "familyName": "#{article.author && article.author.familyName}",
        "email": "#{article.author && article.author.email}",
        "jobTitle": "#{article.author && article.author.jobTitle}",
        "workLocation": "#{article.author && article.author.workLocation}",
        "worksFor": "Company",
        "image": "#{article.author && article.author.image}",
        "url": "#{article.author && article.author.url}",
        "sameAs": !{JSON.stringify(article.author && article.author.sameAs)}
      }],
      "datePublished": "#{article.date}",
      "dateModified": "#{article.updated || article.date}",
      "publisher": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Company",
        "logo": {
          "@type": "ImageObject",
          "url": "...logo-url.jpg"
        }
      },
      "image": "#{article.image}",
      "url": "#{article.url}"
    }
```

The templating language here is pug.

So how would I add a second Person?

```
     "sameAs": !{JSON.stringify(article.author && article.author.sameAs)}
  }
  if (coauthor) return ,{author-2}
  ],
     "datePublished": "#{article.date}",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (slightly roundabout) way to do it would be to build the schema object in javascript beforehand using an unbuffered code block, and then output it into your script tag using `JSON.stringify()`.

Assuming your data is structured such that `article.authors` is an array of authors:

```
-
  let jsonld = {
    '@context': 'http://schema.org',
    '@type': 'Article',
    'headline': article.title,
    'description': article.description,
    'datePublished': article.date,
    'dateModified': article.updated || article.date,
    'publisher': {
      '@type': 'Organization',
      'name': 'Company',
      'logo': {
        '@type': 'ImageObject',
        'url': '...logo-url.jpg'
      }
    },
    'image': article.image,
    'url': article.url
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < article.authors.length; i++) {
    jsonld.authors = jsonld.authors || []
    let author = {
      '@type': 'Person',
      'name': article.authors[i].name,
      'givenName': article.authors[i].givenName,
      'additionalName': article.authors[i].additionalName,
      'familyName': article.authors[i].familyName,
      'email': article.authors[i].email,
      'jobTitle': article.authors[i].jobTitle,
      'workLocation': article.authors[i].workLocation,
      'worksFor': 'Company',
      'image': article.authors[i].image,
      'url': article.authors[i].url,
      'sameAs': JSON.stringify(article.authors[i].sameAs
    }
    jsonld.authors.push(author)
  }

script(type="application/ld+json")= JSON.stringify(jsonld, null, 2)
```